# Transparent particle objects are rendered black in Cycles but in the viewport they look perfectly transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

The membrane layer in transparent or black is displayed correctly in the viewport but as soon as I render it in cycles, it is only displayed in black.
I increased the light paths until I reached 1024 samples. Then I increased min light bounces and min transparent bounces. But more out of desperation. I did not expect that it could bring something. I was rendering with a very high number of samples. I think it was around 300,000.
I'm running out of ideas. The example in the screenshot is rendered with 10,000 samples.
I didn't finish the render because you can see that there won't happen some magic anymore. (Red arrow)

Maybe someone has a tip or two for me. I would be very grateful!

[image: viewport]
[image: render]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images showing your particle settings and material setups. You may add a   simplified [blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  to your question as well that shows the problem so that others may take a look.

Comment: I got it out. Apparently cycles has a problem with transparencies in the emitter system. I converted it and now it works.

Comment: Then please write a complete answer so that other users can learn from what you did.

Comment: I dont know anymore to write..? Convert particle system before render transparency instances - thats it.